# How to set the date in the Angular Date Range Picker to the 1st day of the month

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, daterangepicker

Im using this Angular directive for date range picker

https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

At the moment is sets the default date to current date

How can I set the first date range to be 1st day of the month. How to set the date?

```
<div date-range start="a" end="b"> </div>

{{(a|date)||"pick start"}} {{(b|date)||"pick end"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
var date = new Date();
$scope.a = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
$scope.b = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! Was thinking in that direction too, just new to angular. Thank you!

Comment: @OleksandrFedorov Glad to help you..Mark answer as correct so that other can get help from it.Thanks :)